# Is it possible to use github to host a web application that supports sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, github, github-pages

Github supports static webpages. Sqlite database is a binary file. Can a static webpage with javascript access make queries on the sqlite database in the same folder?

Many web development projects require a database. This is for demonstration purposes only and does not need to support many users.

Comment: As you said Github Pages only supports static websites.
If you want to make queries you execute server side code because you may change the binary file server-side.

You may be able to read the database manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but read-only. [sql.js](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js) is a Javascript SQLite library which compiles the SQLite C library into [Webassembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly).

Here's an example of [loading an existing SQLite database from a URL and querying it](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js#loading-a-database-from-a-server).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// For example: https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database/raw/master/ChinookDatabase/DataSources/Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite
xhr.open('GET', '/path/to/database.sqlite', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = e => {
  var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
  var db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
  var contents = db.exec("SELECT * FROM my_table");
  // contents is now [{columns:['col1','col2',...], values:[[first row], [second row], ...]}]
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Can I use this using SQL Server?

Comment: @carloswm85 No, this is specific to SQLite which has no server, just a file. Connecting to SQL Server from a browser is browser specific and *not recommended* as it exposes your database connection to everyone. You'd write a web app which does the SQL queries hidden behind an API. You can write this in JavaScript with Node.js and the [tedious library](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: So you're saying that what I can do instead is adding to my GitHub hosted web app, an API which does the connection to the external DB? What about authentication to the DB? I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: @carloswm85 While you can write a hosted app that allows direct SQL queries, that's not a good idea. How it's usually done is all the database queries happen in the hosted web app. The JavaScript in the web page would make high level requests of the web app like "show me all the messages for this user" via an API. The API restricts what can be done, hides the details, and controls access to the data. This is too big a topic for StackOverflow. Look into REST APIs.